# How to delete an email permanently using Graph API?

Tags: python, email, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Graph API to delete emails. Below is the code. However I am unable to delete the emails permanently, since it can be recovered from "Recover Deleted Items from Server". Is any one aware of how to do this with the Graph API? Thank you.

```
user = ""
message_id = ""
query_url = url + "users/" + user + "/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '" + message_id + "'"
print(query_url)
bearer_token = "Bearer" + " " + token["access_token"]
headers = {'Authorization': bearer_token, 'Content-type':'application/json'}
response = requests.get(query_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
result = json.loads(response.text)
result_emails = result["value"]

for email in result_emails:
    print email["sender"]["emailAddress"]["address"]
    print email["subject"]

    id = email["id"]
    delete_url = url + "users/" + user + "/messages/" + id
    print(delete_url)
    response = requests.delete(delete_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Comment: As of now you cannot hard delete or permanently delete the messages using MS Graph. Please upvote this [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37635205-allow-messages-to-be-hard-deleted) so that the products team can work on including this feature in future releases

Comment: Thank you, are you aware of any other options to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use the MAPI call (IMAPIFolder::DeleteMessages and use the DELETE_HARD_DELETE flag) to hard delete the items. Here's the documentation for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapifolder-deletemessages

Answer (score 9):

When you hard delete a Message in Exchange (even with MFCMAPI) and you have Single Item Recovery turned on the message will end up in the Recoverable-items/purges folder see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/recoverable-items-folder/recoverable-items-folder. The only time its truly deleted is after the MFA (managed folder assistant) has done its work cycle.

So if you want to copy what a hard delete is doing you can just move the message to the purges folder which will make it invisible to the user and unrecoverable by a user (but an Admin could still recover it).

eg you can just use

```html
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADhAAATs28OAAA=/move
Content-type: application/json

{
  "destinationId": "recoverableitemspurges"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code. You made my life simple :)

Comment: This is an under-appreciated answer! Thank you.